# how to pass a filename as function parameter in python?

Tags: python-3.x, file-handling

I've got a problem to solve that says **. Write a function in python that will take a file name fname and a string s as input. It will return whether s occurs inside the file. It's possible that the file is extremely large so it cannot be read into memory in one shot**
and I've done a solution for that like this

```
import fileinput
def FileAndString(s,filename):
    
    inname =input(filename)
    s =s
    fname= open(fileinput.input(files ='inname'))
    flag = 0
    index = 0
    for line in fname:
        index += 1
        if s in line:
            flag = 1
            break
    if flag == 0:
        print("string", s, "not found")
    else:
        print('String', s, 'Found In Line', index)
FileAndString('goal','fname.txt')
```

and I'm getting an error like this

```
  traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/hp/Desktop/test/repo/file.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "c:/Users/hp/Desktop/test/repo/file.py", line 10, in FileAndString
    index += 1
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\fileinput.py", line 248, in __next__
    line = self._readline()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\fileinput.py", line 366, in _readline
    self._file = open(self._filename, self._mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'inname'
```

and my question is:
is this the right way to do it?
how to pass that fname.txt or any file as a parameter

Comment: In your description of how the function should work, it states that the two arguments of the function should be: `fname` and `s` where `fname` is a string of the filename it wants you to search through, and `s` is the string to look for. You do not have to declare those variables inside of the function, because they are required to be given to the function to work. You already seem to know how `open()` works, so why not just do `open(fname)`?

Comment: if you don't mind can you clarify it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others has already answered, the problem you're having with your code is that you're not opening the file you're giving the function. You're trying to open a string-representation of the variable, not the actual variable.

Here is the solution you're after:

```
def string_in_file(fname, s):
    # Use a context-manager to automatically
    # handle closing of files after you're done.
    with open(fname, "r") as F:
        # Read one line at a time, keeping only
        # that one line in memory.
        for line in F.readlines():
            if s in line:
                return True
        # If none of the lines in the for-loop
        # are True, then the string is not in the file.
        return False
```

Or if you want a single-line solution (which doesn't work the same way, but gives similar results):

```
string_in_file = lambda fname, s: any(s in line for line in open(fname))
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```py
fname= open(fileinput.input(files ='inname'))
```

You've specified 'inname' as a string and not as a variable. Remove the quotes and it will resolve your current error.

Comment: thank you, I've tried it, the error goes but the result in the terminal is "fname.txt" only. I want to check whether the string "s" is in the file or not. the result should be like this:- string", s, "not found" or 'String', s, 'Found In Line', index

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:
`fname= open(fileinput.input(files ='inname'))`

To:
`fname= open(fileinput.input(files = inname))`

You are passing `inname` as a string. That is why the system can't find any directory. Simply unquote your variable and that should do it.

Comment: thank you, I've tried it, the error goes but the result in the terminal is "fname.txt"  only. I want to check whether the string "s" is in the file or not. 
the result should be like this:- 
 string", s, "not found" or 'String', s, 'Found In Line', index"